# Content-Security-Policy and external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, content-security-policy

I am currently developing an android app using Phonegap/Cordova for a hotel client. The app is to download the menu and content from their wordpress site so I need to load image from their live url. I have this working by making some tweaks to the config.xml file and adding the following metatag to each page;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;img-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *">
```

Also in the app they want their Booking facility to be integrated which is provided by their booking supplier in form of Javascript. The above metatag is stopping the booking form from loading (it works when I remove the tag).

You can view the code on my [JSFiddle Page](https://jsfiddle.net/bp3435w4/) or below.

You will see that it works when you run it without the Metatag. I have added the script-src and tried a number of settings from https://content-security-policy.com/ including adding object-src & frame-src.

Please Help

```js
eviivo.availabilitychecker.create('#availabilitychecker', {
  industryTypes: [1],
  allowCrossDomainTracking: true,
  template: 'horizontal'
});
```

```css
<style type='text/css'> </style> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;img-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *"> 


<style type='text/css'>

.eviivo_availabilitychecker {
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
  background: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
.eviivo_title span {
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
.eviivo_submit a {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #F28226 !important;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://securebooking.eviivo.com/DutchmanFY16AH.availabilitychecker.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="availabilitychecker"></div>
```

Comment: You mean the error you are getting `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/bp3435w4/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://securebooking.eviivo.com/mywebsite/DutchmanFY16AH.home?viewname=onli…booking&startdate=06/12/2016&nights=1&adults1=1&industrytype=1&children1=0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Hi.. sorry... It works on both http and https... I added the https on the JSFiddle resource include to get it working with JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have now got this working thank you. I simply needed to add 'unsafe-eval' to the script-src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```js
eviivo.availabilitychecker.create('#availabilitychecker', {
  industryTypes: [1],
  allowCrossDomainTracking: true,
  template: 'horizontal'
});
```

```css
<style type='text/css'> </style> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *; script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *;img-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *"> 


<style type='text/css'>

.eviivo_availabilitychecker {
  width: auto !important;
  height: auto !important;
  color: #333333 !important;
  background: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
.eviivo_title span {
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
.eviivo_submit a {
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  background: #F28226 !important;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://securebooking.eviivo.com/DutchmanFY16AH.availabilitychecker.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="availabilitychecker"></div>
```